# class id fails to hide because of jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the class `z` to hide when the page loads, but it doesn't even if it has a `display: none;`

I noticed that if i add that instruction to the `h2` containg id `x` it works!

Can you help me to make it work?

This is my code:

```js
var data = {
  shop: [{
      item: "Ps3",
      cost: "$150"
    },
    {
      item: "xbox 360",
      cost: "$140"
    }
  ]
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  var x = $('#x');
  var output = '';
  $.each(data.shop, function(index, element) {
    output += element.item + '<br>' + element.cost + '<br>';
  });
  x.html(output);
  $("button").click(function() {
    x.toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
#x {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

.z {
  background-color: red;
  width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="z">
    <h2 id="x"></h2>
  </div>
  <button>Click</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem. You never hide the div-element, not in css or with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this is what you are after - toggling *class z* instead of *id x* (see inline comments for explanation of the changes)

```js
var data = {
  shop: [{
      item: "Ps3",
      cost: "$150"
    },
    {
      item: "xbox 360",
      cost: "$140"
    }
  ]
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  var z = $('.z'); // Grab class z to toggle
  z.css('display','none'); // Hide class z on load
  var x = $('#x');
  var output = '';
  $.each(data.shop, function(index, element) {
    output += element.item + '<br>' + element.cost + '<br>';
  });
  x.html(output);
  $("button").click(function() {
    z.toggle(); // Toggle z on button click
  });
});
```

```css
#x {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.z {
  background-color: red;
  width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="z">
    <h2 id="x"></h2>
  </div>
  <button>Click</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what changes you did? Add an explanation. it's hard to see that you did any changes?

Comment: Whats so hard to understand? I put display none on a div id call  z. As a result any thing that is inside the div call z should be hidden on page load by using display none. In other words the h2 tag and the div itself AKA class z should be hidden on page load because of the the class id call z.I didn't put display none to z on this example because it doesn't work. So to be able to see the h2 tag and the div you will need to press the button to see them. And you can hide them if you press the button again.

Comment: My answer has the solution ^^

Comment: It's working but Aydin is there any way I can keep x and z in css rather than making x to z in css? I don't want two z in the css

Comment: Edited - Try now.

Comment: Sorry If I didn't make sense early but it's now working =) thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you wanted to do, you just had to refer to the class z instead of the id x

```
var z = $('.z');
```

And put a

```
display: none;
```

in z's css ^^

```js
var data = {
  shop: [{
      item: "Ps3",
      cost: "$150"
    },
    {
      item: "xbox 360",
      cost: "$140"
    }
  ]
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  var z = $('.z');
  var output = '';
  $.each(data.shop, function(index, element) {
    output += element.item + '<br>' + element.cost + '<br>';
  });
  z.html(output);
  $("button").click(function() {
    z.toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
#x {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.z {
  background-color: red;
  width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="z">
    <h2 id="x"></h2>
  </div>
  <button>Click</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying that there are other element inside the div and you want them to be also displayed when button is clicked..

Then try this..

```js
var data = {
  shop: [{
      item: "Ps3",
      cost: "$150"
    },
    {
      item: "xbox 360",
      cost: "$140"
    }
  ]
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  var x = $('#x');
  var output = '';
  $.each(data.shop, function(index, element) {
    output += element.item + '<br>' + element.cost + '<br>';
  });
  x.html(output);
  $("button").click(function() {
    x.toggle();
    $('.z').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
#x {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

.z {
  background-color: red;
  width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="z">
    <h2 id="x"></h2>
    <h1>Huh? I don't understand..</h1>
  </div>
  <button>Click</button>
</body>

</html>
```